# It is possible to add css inside a <g:actionSubmit> tag?

Tags: html, css, grails

I mean: I have an upload form:

```
<g:form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input type="file" name="cv" id="cv" style=" max-width:120px"/>
<g:actionSubmit action="upload" name="upload" value="Upload" />
```

Once tag is rendered in the final page, i have

```
<input type="submit" value="Upload" name="_action_upload">
```

That is, the "Upload" button. But, in the input named "cv", as you can see, i have som css to keep the text box to grow too much. (max-width:120px)

My problem is, the Upload button appears now mounted over the text box where the name and path of the file to upload is written, once selected. And I don't know how to manage that, how to move that button and ONLY that button. Is it that possible?

I've tried to add css to the actionSubmit tag itself, but it moves the whole form.

Thank you.

Comment: You can target CSS dependant on the value or name attributes like `input[name="_action_upload"] { margin-top: 10px;`

Comment: It moves the whole form :(

Comment: But thank you for that, i didn't know that was possible.

Comment: Why not just to add `style="..."` into `actionSubmit`? So you would have: `<g:actionSubmit action="upload" name="upload" value="Upload" style="..."/>`. Or instead add an id attribute and use it as a css selector for your css rule...

Comment: My margin-top was an example, use something else. That will target the input only. If the form is moving that is an issue with what CSS you are applying, try changing the padding to see.

Comment: I did it, Eugene, read the last phrase ;)

Comment: Why does it move the whole form? Replace your g:actionSubmit tag by the corresponding plain html input and see whether style="..." moves the form. If does, then it's not a g:actionSubmit issue but rather a problem in the style.

Comment: Reproduce the HTML in a fiddle - No one will have any idea what you are talking about without an exmaple

Comment: Ok, the code in Grails is like i wrote in the question, and the HTML, once the app is up, is this way: `<div class="adjuntacv" style="margin-top:-207px;">
<label style="font-size: 13px;font-weight: bold;color: #673325;" for="adjuntacv">Adjuntar CV:</label>
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" action="/com.publidirecta.azafatas/personal/index">
<input id="cv" type="file" style=" max-width:120px" name="cv">
<input type="submit" value="Upload" name="_action_upload">
<input id="aza" type="hidden" value="blu@msail.com" name="aza">
<br>
</form>
</div>`

Comment: I copied your html to the JS fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/DbPuu/3/ (except the margin-top). Now, can you show what style changes to the submit move the entire form?

Comment: `<input type="submit" value="Upload" name="_action_upload" style="margin-top:10px">` Added style to that line, and it moves the whole form.

Comment: Thanks for the page, btw. i didn't know about before.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Float left your input file. Inputs are inline-block. That is why it was causing the whole line to drop down with the button. Floating it will change it to block.

```
<input id="cv" type="file" style=" max-width:120px; float:left;" name="cv">
```

Comment: Worked perfectly! Thank you very much James.

Answer (score 0):

The way to make the submit button move independently of another button depends on how you need it to be positioned.
You can add a `<br/>` before it; or wrap the form content into a `<table>` and make the two buttons lie in two different `<td>`s. Or use `"vertical-align: top;"` for form elements:

```
form * {
    vertical-align: top;
}
```